# Complex $2$ manifold $M$ with a given real 2 dimensional submanifold which meets all complex limit cycles of foliations of $M$

Tags: complex-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, foliations

Is there a $2$ dimensional   holomorphic manifold $M$ with a closed $2$ dimensional  real submanifold $A$ of $M$ such that for every singular holomorphic foliation of $M$, all leaf with non trivial holonomy must necessarilly intersect $A$.

Two motivations for this questions  are:

1)[The  minimal set problem in the theory  of  $SHF$C of  $\mathbb{C}P^2$](http://www.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1988__68__187_0.pdf)

2)This $RG$ preprint ["A complex Limit cycle Not Intersecting of the real plane"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332383772_A_Complex_Limit_Cycle_Not_intersecting_the_real_Plane)